# Assign Variable in Using For Loop JS

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, for-loop, dom

I am trying to learn how to use for loop to create and assign variables. I have a list of items gathered using:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("category-item-link")
```

it returns:

```
[a.category-item-link, a.category-item-link, a.category-item-link, a.category-item-link, a.category-item-link, a.category-item-link]
```

My goal is to assign each item to a variable called link[0] - link[5] using `for` loop.

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` already returns a collection of elements. `var link = document.getElementsByClassName("category-item-link")`?

Answer (score 1):

Since it already returns a collection of elements, you can just do this (I converted `link` into an array so you can see just the elements):

```js
var link = [...document.getElementsByClassName("category-item-link")];
console.log(link);
```

```html
<a class="category-item-link">Link</a>
<a class="category-item-link">Link</a>
<a class="category-item-link">Link</a>
<a class="category-item-link">Link</a>
<a class="category-item-link">Link</a>
<a class="category-item-link">Link</a>
```

Comment: Thank you for the input!

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByClassName` returns an object with the collection of elements. So you can already access each item to a variable called link[0] - link[5] by this:

```
const link = document.getElementsByClassName("category-item-link")
```

However, for practicing for loop, you may do this:

```
const objs = document.getElementsByClassName("category-item-link")
const link = []

for (let i = 0; i < objs.length; i++) {
    link[i] = objs[i]
}
```

or like this:

```
const objs = document.getElementsByClassName("category-item-link")
const link = []

for (const obj of objs) {
    link.push(obj)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for providing this explanation. I did not know that I had to create an empty list before the for loop:

const link = []

Also in the for loop, I kept putting var in front and getting "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token [". Still new to coding itself and just wondering why I shouldn't have var. 

for (let i = 0; i < objs.length; i++) {
    var link[i] = objs[i]
}